# dynamically calling jquery from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery

Ok so I'm trying to generate a N number of divs and add them to the mark up and call the "Draggable" funtion on them from the Jquery lib.  I've got the adding of divs to the page done, now I just need to call the function and that's where I'm having trouble.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFoo", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction($('#draggable2').draggable());</script>", false);
```

UPDATE:  I've got a work around.  It's not pretty but it works, any suggestions would be great!

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void DragAble(this HtmlGenericControl NewDiv)
    {
        NewDiv.Attributes["class"] = "ui-widget-content";
        string dragmenow = "<script>$(function () { $(\"#" + NewDiv.ClientID + "\").draggable(); });</script>";
        NewDiv.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = dragmenow });
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Where have you defined "myFunction"?

Comment: Since I'm not really sure what needs to happen the "myFunction" doesn't exsist anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Removed the script blocks and added document Ready.

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFoo", "$(function (){myFunction($('#draggable2').draggable());});", true);
```